# Disabling SSL Weak Ciphers with Play! Framework

Tags: ssl, encryption, https, playframework, pci-compliance

Is there a way to disable weak and medium ciphers suites for https, with the standalone Play Framework server?

Couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intention of the standalone server is not to deal with https traffic. The most common pattern is to use something like lighttpd, nginx or apache as a reverse proxy and offload the https processing to that.

Therefore, your question is more suited to whether it is possible to do what you need in one of the above http servers.

Comment: Why can't we use https with Play Framework as it is? Netty seem to have support for https. The problem with e.g. nginx is that it doesn't have support for http 1.1 and websockets.

Comment: You can use HTTPS, but the support for it in Play at the moment is limited, and as you have pointed out the documentation is not the best. I would suggest emailing Nicolas Leroux (he implemented the HTTPS support in Play) to get his thoughts. When I spoke to him last about it, he suggested that the HTTPS support in Play was intended more for web services, and Lighttpd was a better solution.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the information. I'll have to try it out. I want to use it both for webservices and sites.

Comment: SSL works actually great with Play, but as Codemwnci said, the configuration is limited. So I set up a Apache as a frontend and disabled the weak/medium ciphers from Apache. It works perfect. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In Play 2.3, it is possible to do this with the AlgorithmChecker, and the AlgorithmChecker can be set up from a custom SSLEngine provider.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ConfiguringHttps

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play-ws/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/ssl/AlgorithmChecker.scala